# Why cant i change class of element?

Tags: javascript, dom

i want to change class of element, but get it by class(dont work).
If i choosing it by id it works.
i want to make it with pure javascript.

```
function My(){

  var a = document.getElementById('myClass');
  a.className += ' red';

  var b = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
  b.className += ' red';

}
My();
```

Comment: Note how the second method says 'getElement**s**'

Comment: I would advise you to use: `document.querySelector('.class')`

Answer (score 3):

> [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns `array-like object`, not a single element.

Either use `index` of the element or use `loop` to apply class to all the elements having specified class.

```js
function My() {
  var a = document.getElementById('myClass');
  a.className += ' red';
  var b = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
  [].forEach.call(b, function(el) {
    el.className += ' red';
  });
}
My();
```

**Note:** [`Element.classList.add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) could be used instead of `Element.className += ' CLASS_NAME';`

Answer (score 1):

It is because `getElementsByClassName`  returns `array-like object`.

You have to either iterate the array or use index to get the object and assign class.